# mysql with comma separated values

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem in MySQL query.
I need MySQL query to display the following output and I also need to take CSV or Excel or PDF report.

## Table1:

```
id | nos
-------------
1    12,13,14
2    14
3    14,12
```

## Table2:

```
id | values
------------
12   raja
13   rames
14   ravi
```

I want output like this:

```
id | values
---------------------
1    raja, rames, ravi
2    ravi
3    ravi, raja
```

Comment: Can you change your schema to something more SQL-ish such as an association table instead of embedded CSV?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL, it's better to store a single value in a column, not a comma-separated list of values.  See my answer to [Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

You can try this query, but it will be terribly slow and inefficient:

```
SELECT Table1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(Table2.values) AS values
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 ON FIND_IN_SET(Table2.id, Table1.nos)
GROUP BY Table1.id;
```

See the [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

Comment: thanks Bill Karwin for your valuable answer.. from this i got a idea to work in mysql...

Comment: hi Bill Karwin but the output seem to be change in order id | values
---------------------
1    ravi, rames, raja
2    ravi
3    ravi, raja

Comment: Look up the documentation on [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).  You can specify the sort order.