# comma separated values in mysql in to multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I'm ahaving the  problem in mysql query,,I need mysql query for display the following output and also i need to take csv or excel or pdf report .

## Table1:

```
id : nos
---------
1    12,13,14
2    14
3    14,12
```

## Table2:

```
id : values
------------
12   raja
13   rames
14   ravi
```

I want output like this:

```
id  values
---------------------
1   raja
1   rames
1   ravi
2   ravi
3   ravi
3   raja
```

Comment: You should consider to normalize your tables. Storing several values in one column is bad practice.

Comment: A similar question was asked yday by you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075323/mysql-with-comma-separated-values - have you tried writing any queries?

Comment: yes jan but the output slightly differ

Comment: yes jan i am trying to execute differnt queries...

Comment: @raja: Try to use the `FIND_IN_SET()` function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Answer (score 1):

The following query will split out the list, but its not likely to perform well on a large table.

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.values
FROM table1
    JOIN table2 ON CONCAT(',', table1.nos, ',') LIKE CONCAT(',' table2.id, ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your data in table 1 in multiple records.
for example data will be

```
id : nos
---------
1    12
1    13
1    14
2    14
3    14
3    12
```

Then you can use following query to get your result

```
select table1.id, table2.values from table1,table2 where table1.nos=table2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have nos1, nos2, nos3 ... ecc

```
SELECT a.id,a.nos
        b.id,b.values
FROM Table1 as a, Table2 as b
WHERE (a.nos1 = b.id) OR
   (a.nos2 = b.id) OR
   (a.nos3 = b.id)
```