# PHP Split string at certain points

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with a column named *images*

it looks like:

`[image1.jpg],[image2.jpg],[image3.jpg]` etc

how can i extract this information and display each image using PHP like:

```
$sql="SELECT * from table ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
$result=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

echo '<img src="image1.jpg" />';
echo '<img src="image2.jpg" />';
echo '<img src="image3.jpg" />';
```

Comment: use explode function ?

Comment: explode on `,` loop eanch array entry trimming `[]`.... and then consider normalizing your database

Comment: explode. As @MarkBaker mentioned in his comment.

Comment: this question might make your path :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075323/mysql-with-comma-separated-values

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach(explode(',',$result['column']) as $image){
    echo '<img src='.strtr($image,'[]','""').' />';
}
```

Comment: Think you're missing an ending `)` on the strtr call

Comment: $images = explode(',',$result['column']);
echo '<img src='.strtr($images[0],'[]','""').' />';

Comment: how can i get the img src to display like <img src="/img/project-gallery/image1.jpg" />

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. My previous comment prints out exactly this. I don't see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be regexp.

```
preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $field, $images);
$images = $images[1];
```

Now `$images` will contain array of all found images.

Comment: Probably not easier, and certainly too heavyweight for the requirement.

Comment: @MikeW You can test it but I don't think it'll be much slower than other solutions in that case. If of course any difference will be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

**You should use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) & [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) functions to deal with this situation and avoid using regex:**

```
<?php

$data = "[image1.jpg],[image2.jpg],[image3.jpg]";

$data = str_replace("]","", str_replace("[", "", $data));

$exploded = explode("," $data);

?>
```

The array will contain the images each in an element without the "[" and "]", now all you have to do is loop throught it and echo it.